# NSDateFormatter to change a string

Tags: iphone

I have a string in this format "dd.mm.yy" (23.08.10).
I would like to convert them to a Date format using

```
NSDate *currentDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithString:new.date];
```

But i need a format like this: "yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:ss +0000" to compare two dates!
How can I do that? I know that I have to user NSDateFormatter but I dont know how to use it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSDateFormatter* dateformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateformatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yy"];
NSDate *date = [dateformatter dateFromString:dateString];
[dateformatter release];
```

Have a look at the date markup.

[Date_Format_Patterns](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns)